# Does let a = {} create a new scope?

Tags: javascript

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block :

this creates a new block scope

```
{
  StatementList
}
```

For `let a = {  };`  Is a new scope created inside the surrounding curly braces?

Comment: No. In the `let` statement, that's not a block of statements. It's an object initialization expression. The two are not at all the same.

Comment: @Pointy I see. I mixed up the two

Comment: The parser tries to get a block or object expression depending on the context. For example if it was wrapped in parentheses it would try to parse that as an object instead of a block.